# How to test if an array contains a pair of numbers whose product is even?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

How can I write a function that takes an array of integers and returns true if there exists a pair of numbers whose product is even?

What are the properties of even integers? And of course, how do you write this function in Java? Also, maybe a short explanation of how you went about formulating an algorithm for the actual implementation. This is from the book however I am only trying to learn the explanation.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: To check whether or not a number is even the most universal test is to divide by 2 and see if there is a remainder (or more often to see if the remainder is == 0). There may be built in functions in libraries but in my experience this is a sure fire way to test.

Comment: As a hint first I'd say you need two functions one that loops throught the array and another that takes two numbers and determines if their prodcut is even, then you could loop until the `n - 2` element pasing `i` and `i + 1` to the function, if in any moment it returns true then you return true from the first function

Comment: bool result=false; for (int i=0;i<size_of_a;i++) if (!(a[i]&1)) { result=true; break; }

Answer (score 2):

A pair of integers will always produce an even product if at least 1 of them is even. It can't produce an even product if both are odd. Therefore, you just need to check if there is at least 1 even number in the array.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mathematical concept and known fact that, any even number multiplied by any other number is an even number. And so, all  you have to do is return true if any one number in the array is an even number.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, just having one even number is enough.

You only have to iterate until you find an even number, or the end of the array in which case there is no even number in it.

```
public static boolean hasEvenNumber(int[] vals) {
    int i = 0;
    while(i < vals.length) {
        if(vals[i] % 2 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Algorithm is quite simple .

You need a single even number should present in the array of integers .

Because multiple of even number with odd/even number results in a even number . So you can return true if there is an even number .

In java ,

```
public static int  has_even_pair(int [ ] values,int n)  //method definition to find sum
{
      int i;
      for(i=0; i< n; i++)
      {
          if (values[i] % 2 == 0 )
          {
               return 1;

           }

      }

      return 0 ;
 }
```

Comment: why do you need `n` when `values.length` will suffice? Never write Java like C/C++

Comment: Ya you are right . But my point is that i will pass (values.length) from my calling function ,so that i can directly use whenever it is needed.